# Android: How to link sms draft with information about the receiver (like the name)?

Tags: android

if I write a new text message in the Android standard sms app and fill in a receiver and some body text and press the back button Android will save this as a draft. If the receiver is currently in my address book Android tells me also in the draft overview the name or, if the receiver is not in the address book, the number.
So far, so good.

Now I tried to do exactly the same thing on my own and I'm not quite sure why my solution doesn't work.
I've tried the following:

```
// in a Activity
final ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/draft"),
    String[] {"_id", "date", "body", "person"},
    null, null, null);
```

Later in my own cursor-Adapter I tried to get the person-id which links to the contacts table (I thought so). I do it this way:

```
// in my own CursorAdapter (bindView-Method)
Long receiverId = cursor.getLong("person");
```

But what I get is always "0". So what do I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

Btw: Is there any official documentation about the "content://sms"-thing? I only found some forum postings but nothing at developers.android.com!?

Comment: "Btw: Is there any official documentation about the "content://sms"-thing?" -- no, other than telling you that you are not supposed to use it: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks for this hint. I wondered about this lack of information but now it becomes clear. Perhaps then I need to reconsider my application completely. Thanks again.